# Editing application settings of a containerized application after deployment

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

There might be something I fundamentally misunderstand about Docker and containers, but... my scenario is as follows:

- I have created an asp.net core application and a docker image for it.

  - The application requires some settings being added / removed at runtime
  - Also some dll plugins could be added and loaded by the application
  - These settings would normally be stored in appsettings.json and a few other settings files located in predefined relative path (e.g. ./PluginsConfig)
  - I don't know how many plugins will there be and how will they be configured
  - I didn't want to create any kind of UI in the web application for managing settings and uploading plugins - this was to be done on the backend (I need the solution simple and **cheap**)

I intend to deploy this application on a **single server** and the admin user would be able and responsible for setting the settings, uploading plugins etc. It's an internal productivity tool - there might be many instances of this application, but they would not be related at all.

The reason I want it in docker is to have it as self-contained as possible, with all the dependencies being there.

**But how would I then allow accessing, adding and editing of the plugins and config files?**
I'm sure there's a pattern that would allow this scenario.

Comment: Can try to copy the files using docker cp

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are **volumes** and **bind mounts**. You can bind files or directories from a host machine to a container. Thus, host and container can share files.

Sample command (bind mount - (there are also other ways))

```
docker container run -v /path/on/host:/path/in/container image
```

Detailed information for [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) and [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)